# change directory (python) doesnt work in localhost

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

import os os.chdir("c:\Users") 
works in the command prompt but not on localhost (google app engine.)
can anyone help.

Comment: what happens, what exception.. more info please.

Answer (score 6):

AppEngine restricts you from doing things that don't make sense. Your AppEngine application can't go wandering all over the filesystem once it is running on Google's servers, and Google's servers certainly don't have a C: drive.

Whatever you are trying to accomplish by changing directories, it's something that you need to accomplish in a different way in an AppEngine application.